# Export-PfxCertificate not recognized in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, certificate

Good morning, afternoon or evening.

I had some problems with this command. Basically I'm trying to export a .cer certificate as a .pfx one, but for some reason the command to make the export doesn't work.

The error message I get is this one:

The term 'Export-PfxCertificate' is not recognize as a name of a cmdlet, funtion, script archive or program executable.

I run the command I found in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1098614/how-can-i-export-a-certificate-from-mmc-as-a-pfx-file

And is this one:

```
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert .\LONGSTRINGOFHEX -FilePath 'C:\path\to\outfile.pfx' -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password' -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "*doesn't work*" isn't nearly enough information to help you out. Did you get an error? Did it not give you an error? What "*doesn't work*"? How'd you run the command?

Comment: True. I apologize for the lack of information.

Comment: What PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: Thank you. that was the problem.

Comment: @MARIOADRIANDOMINGUEZBUCHELI What was the problem? And what was your solution?